# How to access WiFi network shares from iOS devices

Tags: ios4, bonjour, network-share

I'm wondering how I can access files on a network share from iOS devices? I know that I can discover network shares using [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) protocol but how can I get a list of files&folders and  download files? Should I use [Apple Filing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol) Is there any classes for this in iOS SDK?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This guy implements SMB client for iOS from scratch: https://github.com/38leinaD/tango
This is all I know (:

There are at least two apps that do this sort of thing officially, so it must be possible in some way:
FileBrowser
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8
NetPortal
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netportal-access-files-on/id323133602?mt=8